# Перевод из дюймов в см и наоборот

Tags: c++builder, c++

Вот код. Он не работает, наотрез не пойму почему. Помогите найти ошибку. Заранее благодарю.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    double iduim = 1, ism = 2.24, u = 0;
    char con, dorsm;
    do {
        cout << "enter amount:";
        cin >> u;
        cout << "\n enter duim or sm:";
        cin >> dorsm;
        switch (dorsm)
        case 'duim':
        {
            cout << "\n" << u << "duim = " << (int) (u * ism);
            break;
        }

        case 'sm':
        {
            cout << "\n" << u << "sm = " << (int) (u * iduim);
            break;
        }
        default:
        {
            cout << "Wrong operation!";
        }
        cout << "n Continue (y,n)?";
        cin >> con;
    } while (con == 'y');
}
```

Comment: А что мешает применить отладчик? Посмотрите, какая из переменных принимает не то значение, которое вы ожидали, да и дело с концом. Неужели такую тривиальную проблему надо выносить на обозрение всего мира?

И ещё: "не работает" -- очень плохое описание проблемы. Не компилируется? Вылетает при запуске? Форматирует жёсткий диск? Выдаёт неверный ответ? В какой строке ошибка, какая, точное сообщение?

Comment: там куча ошибок вылетает, но автор вопроса не удосужился все описать, этим отбил желание помогать

Comment: Ну `'duim'` никакой C/C++ компилятор не поймёт.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. кейсы надо брать в блок {}
2. вот что пишет студия: "выражение switch (dorsm) должно иметь
       целочисленный или перечисляемый тип"

Answer (score 1):

Потому что

```
iduim = 1
```

Должно быть

```
iduim = 0.394
```

И `ism = 2.24` должно быть  `ism = 2.54`

Comment: ладно, согласен с замечанием, суть не в том
http://codepad.org/P7ry3xSH
- вот. не работает не потому